# Angular app can not resolve main.ts, polyfile.test and style.css

Tags: angular, docker, npm, node-modules

I am trying to run an Angular app within a Docker container.

I did the following steps:

1) Installed npm (v.3.5.2) and node (v. 12.15.0) and angular CLI (v. 9.0.1) on my machine

2) Created a angular project on my machine (`ng new mean-app --skip-install`)

3) Navigated inside the project and created a Dockefile with the following content:

```
From node:12.15.0-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/

RUN ["npm","install"]

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 4200/tcp

CMD ["npm", "start", "--", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--poll", "500"]
```

4) Then I built the container image (`sudo docker built -t mean-app`)

5) Then I started started the container (`sudo docker run -it --rm -p 4200:4200 -v ${pwd}/src:/app/src mean-app`)

Result:

The build is successfull, the container starts, however I get the following error message:

```
ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-node&sockPath=/sockjs-node ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/app/src/main.ts' in '/app'
ERROR in multi ./src/polyfills.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/app/src/polyfills.ts' in '/app'
ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/app/src/styles.css' in '/app'
ERROR in Must have a source file to refactor.
```

I can not find any other post where people get these error messages... I would appreciate any help very much.

Comment: I just execed into the running cotainer - The npm and node versions are the same as on my machine.

Comment: the src folder inside the container is empty. So I am currently suspecting an issue with the following command in the Dockerfile: 

`COPY . /app`

I already tried 

`COPY . /app/` and also to add `COPY ./src /app/src`

No success the directory stays empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue mysel, please find my solution below:

I got the error messages because the `src` folder within the container appeared to be empty and therefore main.ts, polyfills.ts and style.css were not available for compilation inside the container.

Reason for that is that I started the container with the following command: 
`sudo docker run -it --rm -p 4200:4200 -v ${pwd}/src:/app/src mean-app`

Even though I copied the src folder (s. Dockerfile), I then mounted the folder to my local system when I started the container (s. command). The issue with the command is that I used ${pwd} instead of $(pwd), which made the mount invalid. This lead to an empty `src` folder and a therefore also to the failed compilation.

Answer (score 0):

A complete reinstall of *node modules* worked for me.

`npm ci`